# JFrame doesn't respond to pressed keys after switching JPanels in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, cardlayout

I'm new to java and I'm trying to create a Space Invaders game as my first "bigger" desktop project. Currently I've added some design patterns to [Space Invaders Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/spaceinvaders/), but I've been trying to add a menu for several days and nothing I had found on the net really worked. After actually finding some useful code and adding it to **SpaceInvaders** class, I'm stuck. The problem is, after i choose "New Game" from main menu, the game starts and everything works, besides the player - it should move with arrow keys and shoot with alt, but it doesn't respond at all.
Here's the part of the code:

#### SpaceInvaders.java (main class)

```
public class SpaceInvaders extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Commons {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JButton play = new JButton("New Game");
JButton scores = new JButton("High Scores");
JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
JButton mainMenu = new JButton("Main Menu");

CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel game = new JPanel();
JPanel menu = new JPanel(); 
Board board = new Board();

public SpaceInvaders() { 
    panel.setLayout(layout);        
    addButtons();

    setSize(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGTH);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Space Invaders");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    requestFocus();

}

private void addButtons() {

    play.addActionListener(this);
    scores.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    mainMenu.addActionListener(this);

    //menu buttons
    menu.add(play);
    menu.add(scores);
    menu.add(exit);

    //background colors
    menu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    //adding children to parent Panel
    panel.add(menu,"Menu");
    panel.add(board,"Game");

    add(panel);
    layout.show(panel,"Menu");

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    Object source = event.getSource();

    if (source == exit) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (source == play) {
        //add(new Board());
        layout.show(panel, "Game");
    } 

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new SpaceInvaders(); 

}
}
```

#### Board.java

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements Runnable, Commons { 

private Dimension d;
private ArrayList aliens;
private Player player = Player.getInstance();
private Shot shot;

private int alienX = 150;
private int alienY = 5;
private int direction = -1;
private int deaths = 0;

private boolean ingame = true;
private final String expl = "../spacepix/explosion.png";
private final String alienpix = "../spacepix/alien.png";
private String message = "Game Over";

private Thread animator;

public Board() 
{
    //addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    d = new Dimension(BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGTH);
    setBackground(Color.black);          
    gameInit();
    getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
    getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");
    getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "shoot");
    getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 0), "alt");
    getActionMap().put("shoot", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x = player.getX();
            int y = player.getY();
            if (ingame) { 
                if (!shot.isVisible())
                    shot = new Shot(x, y);
            } 
        }
    });
    getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
            player.moveLeft();
        }
    });
    getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            player.moveRight();
        }
    });
    getActionMap().put("alt", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });

    setDoubleBuffered(true);
}

public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    gameInit();
}

public void gameInit() {

    //aliens work, so I deleted them form here

 //   player = new Player();
    shot = new Shot();

    if (animator == null || !ingame) {
        animator = new Thread(this);
        animator.start();
    }
}

//drawing aliens, players, bombs, shots and background also works

public void animationCycle()  {

    if (deaths == NUMBER_OF_ALIENS_TO_DESTROY) {
        ingame = false;
        message = "Game won!";
    }

    // player
    player.act();

    // player's shot
    if (shot.isVisible()) {
        Iterator it = aliens.iterator();
        int shotX = shot.getX();
        int shotY = shot.getY();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Alien alien = (Alien) it.next();
            int alienX = alien.getX();
            int alienY = alien.getY();

            if (alien.isVisible() && shot.isVisible()) {
                if (shotX >= (alienX) && 
                    shotX <= (alienX + ALIEN_WIDTH) &&
                    shotY >= (alienY) &&
                    shotY <= (alienY+ALIEN_HEIGHT) ) {
                        ImageIcon ii = 
                            new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(expl));
                        alien.setImage(ii.getImage());
                        alien.setDying(true);
                        deaths++;
                        shot.die();
                    }
            }
        }

        int y = shot.getY();
        y -= 4;
        if (y < 0)
            shot.die();
        else shot.setY(y);
    }

// aliens
// bombs
// those work
}

public void run() {

    long beforeTime, timeDiff, sleep;

    beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (ingame) {
        repaint();
        animationCycle();

        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
        sleep = DELAY - timeDiff;

        if (sleep < 0) 
            sleep = 2;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    gameOver();
}
```

#### Player.java

```
public class Player extends Sprite implements Commons{

private static Player instance;
private final int START_Y = 280; 
private final int START_X = 270;

private final String player = "../spacepix/player.png";
private int width;

private Player() {

    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(player));

    width = ii.getImage().getWidth(null); 

    setImage(ii.getImage());
    setX(START_X);
    setY(START_Y);
}

public static synchronized Player getInstance() {

    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new Player();
    }

    return instance;
}

public void act() {
    x += dx;
    if (x <= 2){
        x = 2;
    }             
    if (x >= BOARD_WIDTH - 2*width) {
        x = BOARD_WIDTH - 2*width;
    }
    //dx = 0;
}

public void moveLeft(){
    dx = -2;
}

public void moveRight(){
    dx = 2;
}
}
```

Could anyone show me what to do for it to work? I'm probably either wrongly initializing player or switching from board to menu, but I've been trying to fix it for a few hours and I'm out of ideas now. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'd just like to add that everything worked before I added the menu. And if someone needs it, I can upload the whole code.

Comment: I'm almost positive this is a focus issue.

Comment: Well, I tried clicking inside the window, but nothing changed.

Comment: This *is* a focus problem. Nothing to do with *window focus* - its component focus. Mixing up focusable and non-focusable components with key listeners is just *asking* for trouble. Or you simply dropped adding the key listener for player somewhere. Hard to tell without knowing the layout hierarchy of the window.

Comment: Don't use `KeyListener`, unless you're writing some control that also manages focus.  Instead use the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which was designed to overcome this limitation and make the code more reusable

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, it's the first time I've heard of it. Thanks for the tips, I'll try doing so asap.

Comment: It works, thanks. Code updated, but in case someone wanted to use it, it still needs a few tweaks.